# What was the true purpose of Schrödinger's cat experiment?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

It was common knowledge to me that Schrödinger's cat experiment explained how, by using quantum mechanics, the observation of an object determines what it is doing, and that if say you put a cat in a box with a bomb and close it the cat is both dead and alive at the same time until the box is opened. I recently learned that this thought experiment was to disprove quantum theory by displaying how stupid the theory was with this cat and box. So which is it? Are quantum mechanics cool, or stupid?

Comment: Quantum Mechanics is a mathematical representation of reality, like Newton's laws of Motion.

Comment: The true purpose is to confuse generations of students.

Comment: Have the schools stopped teaching that the **definition** of "dead" is "not alive"?

Comment: see this relevant answer of mine https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/685496/is-the-observed-schr%c3%b6dingers-cat-still-in-a-superposition/685497#685497

Comment: This Veritasium video talks about this. - [Parallel Worlds Probably Exist. Here’s Why](https://www.facebook.com/veritasium/videos/parallel-worlds-probably-exist-heres-why/339179977597625/)

Answer (score 3):

The purpose of the thought experiment is to call attention to the fact that the existing interpretations of quantum mechanics were at that time (as they are to some extent today) vague about exactly when a wave function collapses, or what causes that collapse.   If someone says "the wave function collapses at the moment of observation", then it is reasonable to ask what constitutes an observation.  By way of illustrating that, one might ask whether, for example, a cat counts as an observer.

But:  No cat is ever both alive and dead and nobody has ever seriously contemplated such a thing; the **meaning** of the word "dead" is "not alive".  One can certainly contemplate the possibility of a cat that is **neither** alive nor dead, but in some state that is a linear combination of the two, and can likewise contemplate the possibility that the human who opens the box is then in a linear combination of "sure I saw it dead" and "sure I saw it alive".  Schrodinger is inviting us to give some thought to those possibilities.  As far as I'm aware, there's no evidence that he was trying to point us to any one particular conclusion.